# Run method in MyRunnable not calling

Tags: java, multithreading

Why MyThread's run method calls If I pass MyRunnable to create a thread. But If I use Thread class my results are different. below is the code which makes confuse me.
Please give any inputs.

```
public class ThreadDemo {

     public static void main(String[] args) 
        { 
            new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
            new MyThread().start(); 
            new MyThread(new MyRunnable()).start(); 
        } 

}

class MyThread extends Thread 
{ 
    MyThread() {} 
    MyThread(Runnable r) {super(r); } 
    public void run() 
    { 
        System.out.print(" Inside Thread ");
    } 
} 
class MyRunnable implements Runnable 
{ 
    public void run() 
    { 
        System.out.print(" Inside Runnable"); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `MyThread.run()` method is overriding `Thread.run()` - and it's the `Thread.run()` implementation which calls the `run` method on the `Runnable` passed into the constructor. As [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29):

> If this thread was constructed using a separate Runnable run object, then that Runnable object's run method is called; otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.

If you change your `MyThread.run()` method to:

```
@Override
public void run() 
{ 
    System.out.print(" Inside Thread ");
    super.run();
}
```

... it will print "Inside Thread" then "Inside Runnable" for the final call, i.e. if you trim your `main` method to *just*

```
new MyThread(new MyRunnable()).start();
```

the result will be

```
  Inside Thread
  Inside Runnable
```

Comment: Well, the order of the printed lines is system-dependent.

Comment: @KodeCharlie: I don't see how. Bear in mind this is within a single thread - how could it print "Inside Runnable" first, when the `MyRunnable.run()` method is only called *after* "Inside Runnable" is printed by `MyThread.run()`?

Comment: Single thread? I don't get you.  There are 4 threads -- the main thread, and three that are launched from main.  Who prints first is an artifact of the how the system executes the threads -- unless there is an explicit priority given to said threads.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @KodeCharlie: I was talking just about the final call. Will clarify that in the answer.